# Choice of deflator in OLS

Tags: regression, least-squares, bias-correction

I am running a pooled OLS model and am not able to internalize change in coefficients/ significance due to change in deflator. The OLS specification is as follows:

Market Value = Constant + A1*Profit + A2* Book Value + A3* NPA + error term

I get different results when I deflate all above variable (both dependent and independent) by 1) Market Value and 2) Book Value. The coefficients change as well as the statistical significance (robust errors used). I use the deflator to control for heteroskesdasticity and I have 150 observations. What can be the likely explanation for change in coefficients by using just a scaled form of an equation ? Any help will be appreciated - I am stuck trying to understand the underlying statistical reason.

Ash

Comment: Clarification- The deflator used are period opening values of MV and BV, and the variables in specification are period ending value. So no variable takes a consistent value of 1 after deflation and is therefore not dropped off.

Comment: How are you deflating by Market Value? (i.e. Market Value/ Market Value = 1). Do you mean $MarketValue_i/\sum_i MarketValue$?

Comment: Deflating by prior period MV. DV takes form MV(t)/ MV (t-1) and all IV are also deflated by MV(t-1)

Comment: It appears that this is a time-series model so that simply "deflating" period-ending values of MV and BV by their period-opening values might not be adequate to remove substantial problems. More detail about the data at hand and the precise question you are trying to answer might give you a better chance at receiving a useful answer. If I am correct that these are time-series data, I'd recommend that you add the `time-series` tag and the `regression` tag to your question, too, to bring the question to the attention of users who are focused on such applications.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is panel data , 30 firms across 5 years. My question is not about model fit but simply whether one should expect to observe different coefficients and P Value when estimating Y/A  = Constant +  X1/A + X2/A as compared to Y/B = Constant + X1/B + X2/B where A and B are positive real numbers and the method used is pooled OLS.

Answer (score 0):

A scale effect issue which is well documented in capital market research in accounting literature. Refer Barth and Clinch (2009) as a starting point.